# is it possible to access pdf file from iphone and upload to the server ios

Tags: ios

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *basePath = ([paths count] > 0) ? [paths objectAtIndex:0] : nil;
NSString *pdfFilePath =[basePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myPDF.pdf"];
NSLog(@"pdf file %@",pdfFilePath);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If you were to encounter a question formatted like this yourself, would you be encouraged to answer it? Please take a look at the "How to ask" page: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to upload files to a server, it is common to use the Alamofire library available at: https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire